# within python (temporarily) redefine windows special locations

Tags: python

After a lot of digging I have found that:

```
XDG_DATA_HOME == CSIDL_PERSONAL,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA   
XDG_CONFIG_HOME = CSIDL_APPDATA, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA
```

for Windows. This is shown via:

```
print(GLib.get_user_data_dir())
print(GLib.get_user_config_dir())
```

& placing some `gtk-3.0` config in `C:\Users\<user>\...`

Because I have been moving some binary files around (for a frozen appilcation) I need to ensure `GTK` can find some key directories (`etc` and `share`). 
It seems I need to temporarily set these variables, but `os.environ['...] =` does not work.

Any ideas?  Worst-case I have `etc/` and `share/` in the `root` but I have been trying to keep it de-cluttered.

Comment: Those values are stored in the Windows registry, so you should be able to change them using the `_winreg` (or `winreg` in Python 3) module (assuming you have sufficient privileges). I think they're in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to permanently redefine them, I want to temporarily set them. In *NIX I can redefine/extend XDG_* on a per-app basis (os.environ['XDG_DATA_HOME'] += '/some/arbitary/path'. Now Windows does not use XDG but the equiv for GTK/pyGObject are the CSIDL variables. I was hoping to locally redefine them for my app

Comment: Windows has "run as" where you can execute something using different credentials (i.e. as another user). Perhaps you could set up a separate user account for testing and define their folders accordingly. Alternatively you could make the modifications temporary by changing registry and then restoring it yourself depending on the workflow.

Comment: Seems really risky (and yes the keys are the ones that hold the special locations). If the application crashes or cannot gain access to the reg to set it back, two very key 'variables' will be pointing to a defunct location and everything from outlook to acrobat will regent their data in my apps folder.  I was hoping there was just some variable that could be set, like in windows, where extending the search dir is easy and common. I was also hoping gtk provided suitable user overidable variables. I guess not. Thanks anyway

Comment: I still think you could set up another user account with the desired folders and then use the [runas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas) API to execute the process you want under that account.

Comment: but as mentioned, this is for a frozen application and thus deployment to others who may or may not have admin rights and thus an automated check,create,runas cannot equally be relied upon